# how to return value from while loop in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11, while-loop

I have changed the scenario of the originally code. Generally, given that there is a rate of the factory producing certain number of sweets per day. For example, rate is 0.5. And if at first (day 0) the factory produce 1000 sweets. After day 1, the factory should be produced 1000*(1+0.5)=1500 sweets. And after day 2, the factory should be produced 1000*(1+0.5)*(1+0.5)=2250 sweets. And now i want to create a function to calculate the number of sweets that the factory has produced within a particular days

```
int ProduceSweets(float rate, int swt=10, int days=6)
{
// i want to calculate the number of sweets the factory has produced.
while (days !=0)
{
    swt = swt* (1+rate);
    -- days;

}
return swt;
   
}

int main()
{
float rate;
int swt;
int days;

cout << "enter the number of sweets that the factory has produced" <<endl;
cin >> swt ;
cout << "enter the rate of producing sweets per day" << endl;
cin >> rate ;
cout << "enter the number of days that the factory is producing sweets" <<endl;
cin >> days ;

ProduceSweets(rate, swt, days);
cout << " the factory has produced " << swt << "sweets" << endl;
}
```

However, if the rate is 0.5, the sweets is 1000 and the days is 2, the output(aka total sweets that the factory has been produced) should be 2250. But the output is still 1000 after i run the program. I cannot return the swt value from the function to the caller. What have i do wrong?

Comment: A return value is only useful if you actually capture and use it. `swt = ProduceSweets(...);`

Comment: Thank you so much! I have made a stupid mistake. Thanks for your reminder. I could get the right value now!!

Comment: @sidjfs consider deleting or closing the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not assign the result of your function to anything, so the value is lost.

Comment: the line ProduceSweets(rate, swt, days);should be swt = ProduceSweets(rate, swt, days)

Comment: That line calls the function. The functions returns the desired result. Where does this value go? What do you assign it to?

Comment: the return value from the function should be assigned to swt if you want to use the result as you do in the output

Comment: Should be, well... You pass swt by value, so your function gets only a copy of it. Changes to swt inside your function have no effect on the parameter you passed. Your function returns an int and that int is not used so the result is lost.

Comment: when you call the function ProduceSweets, the 3 parameters are all copied to local parameters, which are private to the function. the variable swt in main does not change because the local copy in the functon change. these 2 variabels are different variables despite they have the same name.... try google scope rules in c++

Comment: Thank you guys. Yes you are right. I did not assign the return value to anything. I made a stupid mistakes. Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

U.W. is correct. The easiest solution is to do something like: `int x= ProduceSweets(rate,swt, days);`, followed by `cout << " the factory has produced " << x << "sweets" << endl;`.

Comment: yes! i have got it. Thank you so much for your help.